# Why deosn't this rewriterule work?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

The company I currently work for has a 3+ years live site based on symfony 2.8. Recently it was deployed for testing to a new customer. The images on the original are accessed in the html like "/bundles/bundlename/images/image.png".

On the customers server however the whole thing is under a subfolder, so image url's should be like "/d2s/bundles/bundlename/images/image.png".
We have a .htaccess file in the project's web dir like this:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    FollowSymLinks On

    RewriteRule /?bundles/(.*)$ /d2s/bundles/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

   [,,,]
```

All other parts work fine, in apache conf's virtualhost AllowOverride is set to All. But this url rewrite just doesn't work, like if it wasn't there at all.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I just realised I made a conceptional error. Since the whole application is in a subfolder (/d2s/) a call to /bundles/ will never reach the app's docroot and thus the .htaccess. No matter what I put in it wont work this way..
If a moderator reads this pleas close down this question!

Answer (score 0):

Set a correct RewriteBase. Don't start your internal RewriteRule patterns or substitutions with a `/`. If you're going to stick with with the auto determination of a RewriteBase equivalent, it should precede all other rules.